# Need insights on best approach for Querying multiple tables using Specifications in Spring JPA

Tags: java, mysql, spring-data-jpa, projection, specifications

There is a requirement to fetch data from multiple tables based on a set of filters, each of which might be null.
For example:
Entities A, B and C

Associations:

```
A<->B Many to One
A<->C One to One
```

Specifications can solve issue of nullable filters. Along with Join<X,Y> we should be able to solve this.
However, using Join<A,B> still generates Specification of entity A only, as a result of which we get Page of Entity A. But I need attributes of B and C as well.

To solve this I attempted to create a custom projection with attributes from A, B and C, and created Specification of type A with Join<A,B> and Join<A,C> like below:

ProjectionWithAttributesOfABC fetchAttributes(Specification spec)

This results in `NoSuchElementException`

To get it working functionally I added B and C within Entity A and annotated them like below:

```
@OneToOne(FetchType.EAGER) C cInstance;
@ManyToOne(FetchType.EAGER) B bInstance;
```

This works, but I think this will cause N+1 query issue in production.
When I hit the API to fetch details using @OneToOne based approach, I can see in debug mysql log that there are many queries generated to fetch Entity C.

Using specifications with Projections will solve my issue but seems like its not supported in spring as of now.

I am not able to figure out a way to solve this issue.
Please share insights as to how I can tackle this.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a [custom method in your repository interface](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behavior) and implement it yourself using an injected `EntityManager`.

You can use a query string or the criteria API.
With the latter you may reuse any `Specification` you might have lying around.